# Convert Integer Sensor data to String

Tags: arduino

I am working with a sensor which constantly sends numbers (readings) to the arduino. I also have a BLE device and want to send it through the BLE_Shield which is connected to my phone, my problem is that the code on my app I have does not support integers, so I am wondering, how can I have the reading numbers converted to a string?

Here is my code:

```
    #include <Wire.h>
    #include <LIDARLite.h>
    #include <SoftwareSerial.h>


    LIDARLite myLidarLite;
    SoftwareSerial BLE_Shield(4,5);


    void setup()  // Called only once per startup
    {
    BLE_Shield.begin(9600);
    myLidarLite.begin(0, true);
    myLidarLite.configure(0);
    }

    void loop(){

    if(BLE_Shield.available()) {
        delay(750);
        BLE_Shield.write("Sensor:"+myLidarLite.distance());  //myLidarLite.distance() is the distance.
      }
```

When I use that my app cannot read it, but when I replace it with this:

```
BLE_Shield.write("Sensor:123");
```

Then it is successfully received.

Comment: May `sprintf` and all variants help you ?